# How to configure travis yml for running webdriverio tests on osx with android emulator?

Tags: android, node.js, android-emulator, travis-ci, webdriver-io

I have few automation tests using webdriverio which I want to execute on osx using travis ci.

Need some help or examples on travis ci + android sdk + android emulator + nodejs (webdriverio)

Please let me know anyone is having an example .yml file for such tests.

My confusion is which should be the language android or node_js?

How to launch the android emulator ? Is it possible to get existing android avds to just start instead of creating new ones as they take too much time?

[This](https://github.com/rahulmr/wdio-appium-service/blob/master/.travis.yml) is my current travis yml.